# Not getting firestore document field data even though document has couple of fields

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have migrated the firebase real time data to cloud firestore through the below nodejs script:

```
var fireastoreDB = admin.firestore();
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("/users");
let items = [];
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
 let collectionRef =  fireastoreDB.collection("users");
  snapshot.forEach(item => {
  collectionRef.doc(item.key).set(item.val());
});
```

I got the data into cloud firestore. Now I have to implement REST APIs for this data in the nodejs.

```
var docusRef = db.collection("users").get().then( (data) => {
console.log(data);
data.forEach( item => {
let docObj =  item.data();
console.log(docObj['Coins']);
console.log(docObj['Coins']['Total Coins']);
});
});
```

from this code, I am able to get all documents field data. But when I am trying to get specific document data directly I was getting undefined(exists: false) but data was there under this document.

```
var db = admin.firestore();
var docusRef = db.collection("users").doc('Atest - 12345')
docusRef.get().then(function (col) {
  var name=col.get("Coins");
  console.log(name); // undefined & exists: false
});
```

when i have added document/fields manually from firebase console, I was getting data.
Is this issue with migrated data or what?
Can anyone please find the issue.

Comment: As a side note, note that you could use some Batched writes for your data migration, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.WriteBatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get) method returns "a Promise resolved with a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) containing the current document contents". Therefore you have to use the [`data()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#data) method of the `DocumentSnapshot` to get the fields of the document, as follows:

```
docusRef.get().then(function (col) {
  var name=col.data().Coins;
  console.log(name); 
});
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Comment: yes marked @Renaud Tarnec, Just now i posted one more question on bigquery. Can you look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55806105/export-databasehaving-nested-documents-from-cloud-firestore-to-bigquery-using - i am getting issues when exporting firestore data into bigquery. Can you please help me.